# Is there a way to get the enums in VBA?

Tags: vba, reflection, enums

Is there a way to get the enums in VBA? Something like this example for C#, but for VBA?

```
using System;

class EnumsExampleZ
{
    private enum SiteNames
    {
        SomeSample = 1,
        SomeOtherSample = 2,
        SomeThirdSample = 3
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Type enumType = typeof(SiteNames);
        string[] enumName = enumType.GetEnumNames();

        for (int i = 0; i < enumName.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(enumName[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Lets say we have the following:

```
Enum FruitType
    Apple = 1
    Orange = 2
    Plum = 3
End Enum
```

How can we display on the immediate window these:

```
Apple
Orange
Plum
```

Comment: in `VBA` enums are just named constants and since `VBA` doesn't have reflection like .NET applications there is no way to extract strings from values, or to parse a string into a value. You have to manually code this.

Comment: I made a function to make it dynamically ! You can find it at this link :
https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1881376/logiciels/microsoft-office/general-vba/contribuez/outil-e-recuperer-nom-membres-d-enumeration/ It looks in the VBE project and search "Public Enum " & strEnumName
And it return a Dictionnary with all the elements in the Enum. You should Activate Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 and Microsoft Scripting Runtime. Also you should go in :
Excel Options --> Trust Center --> Macro Settings --> Developer Macro Settings
and check "Trust access to the VBA project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parsing the VBA code yourself with the VBIDE Extensibility library is going to appear nice & simple at first, and then you're going to hit edge cases and soon realize that you need to actually implement that part of the VBA spec in order to properly and successfully parse every possible way to define an enum in VBA.

I'd go with [the simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41578505/1188513).

That said [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) is doing pretty much exactly that, and exposes an **experimental** COM API that allows you to enumerate *all* declarations (and their references) in the VBE, effectively empowering your VBA code with reflection-like capabilities; as of 2.0.11 (the latest release), the code would look something like this:

```
Public Enum TestEnum
    Foo
    Bar
End Enum

Public Sub ListEnums()
    With New Rubberduck.ParserState
        .Initialize Application.VBE
        .Parse
        Dim item As Variant
        For Each item In .UserDeclarations
            Dim decl As Rubberduck.Declaration
            Set decl = item
            If decl.DeclarationType = DeclarationType_EnumerationMember Then
                Debug.Print decl.ParentDeclaration.Name & "." & decl.Name
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

And *in theory* would output this:

```
TestEnum.Foo
TestEnum.Bar
```

However we (ok, *I did*) broke something around the 2.0.9 release, so if you try that in 2.0.11 you'll get a runtime error complaining about an invalid cast:

[image: broken experimental API]

That <s>should be</s> *is* an easy fix that [we'll patch up by 2.0.12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WX5o.png), but note that at that point the API is still experimental and very much subject to change (feature requests are welcome!), so I wouldn't recommend using it for anything other than toy projects.

Comment: Just out of curiosity now - why did you need the functionality to ListEnums in Rubberduck?

Comment: I get  user type not defined on: _New Rubberduck.ParserState_  which seems odd as it is installed.

Comment: @QHarr that API may have been modified in breaking ways semi-recently... I'll verify & get back to you.

Comment: @QHarr confirmed, the API is currently unavailable. Probably since the introduction of parse task suspension and/or the COM API clean-up (the RD type library is now only exposing what we explicitly expose) - I'll open an issue on the project repository, the experimental COM/reflection API should still be there.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the update. I have added the 64 version.

Answer (score 11):

There is no built-in function, though it is easy enough to roll your own in a concrete case:

```
Enum FruitType
    Apple = 1
    Orange = 2
    Plum = 3
End Enum

Function EnumName(i As Long) As String
    EnumName = Array("Apple","Orange","Plum")(i-1)
End Function
```

If you have several different enums, you could add a parameter which is the string name of the enum and `Select Case` on it.

Having said all this, it might possible to do something with scripting the VBA editor, though it is unlikely to be worth it (IMHO).

Comment: it's OK if arrays are startet from zero. Otherwise you schould use `LBound()`

Comment: @LeonRom The `Array()` function returns 0-based arrays (unless you are using the horrid `Option Base 1` at the top of your module).

Comment: @John Coleman Thanks but it seems You are wrong. Try to execute `Debug.Print LBound(Array("Apple", "Orange", "Plum"))` inside your example and with/without `Opyion Base 1`. You'll see different values: **1**/**0**.

Comment: @LeonRom  `Option Base 1` changes the default behavior of the `Array` function. My last comment explicitly mentioned that. Doing this in production code is considered by many to be a bad idea. If you want to use `Option Base 1` then you can of course tweak the above code if you want. I myself never use it and regard it as a minor design flaw in VBA.

Answer (score 6):

If the reason you're looking for enum names is because you mean to use them in a user interface, know that even in C# that's bad practice; in .net you could use a `[DisplayAttribute]` to specify a UI-friendly display string, but even then, that's not localization-friendly.

In [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) you can use Excel itself to remove *data* from your *code*, by entering it into a table, that can live in a hidden worksheet that can literally act as a *resource file*:

[image: localized captions]

Then you can have a utility function that gets you the caption, given an enum value:

```
Public Enum SupportedLanguage
    Lang_EN = 2
    Lang_FR = 3
    Lang_DE = 4
End Enum


Public Function GetFruitTypeName(ByVal value As FruitType, Optional ByVal langId As SupportedLanguage = Lang_EN) As String
    Dim table As ListObject
    Set table = MyHiddenResourceSheet.ListObjects("FruitTypeNames")
    On Error Resume Next
    GetFruitTypeName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(value, table.Range, langId, False)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then GetFruitTypeName = "(unknown)"
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Or something like it. That way you keep code with code, and data with data. And you can quite easily extend it, too.

Comment: Well, pretty much my reason was that I noticed that it is doable in .Net and I simply thought about VBA. No particular reason, just curiosity.

Comment: This might be the best solution, even with just one language. Enum-To-String is a lookup, a data-structure, and should be represented as such. Tables are a great way to stored data!

Answer (score 4):

No - there is no native way to do this. You'd need to fully parse all of the user code *and* read the type libraries of any loaded projects *and **finally*** determine what scope each reference was referring to.

Enumerations can't be treated like reference types in VBA, and this due to the deep roots that VBA has in COM.  Enums in VBA are more like aliases, and in fact, VBA doesn't even enforce type safety for them (again, because of COM interop - MIDL specs require that they are treated as a DWORD).

If you really need to do this in VBA, a good workaround would be to create your own enumeration class and use that instead.

Comment: What do you mean by enumeration class? A class with a list in it?

Comment: @Vityata - That could be one implementation - I was thinking more like a container class holding key - value pairs.  The type strictness would be enforced by the fact it was a reference type.

Comment: So, theoretically an array of strings would be ok, instead of whole new class?

Comment: @Vityata - Depends on what you're using it for.  John Coleman's method would be the one I'd go with if you're only concerned with name lookups.  If you're concerned with enforcing type adherence, I would go with rolling your own enum class.

Comment: How would this class would like? Something like this: http://pastebin.com/CR46tP73

Comment: @Vityata - Yeah, something along those lines.

Comment: seems horribly inefficient to make a class for every enum. That might be lightweight in some language that let's you define a class inside any code-file `Begin Class MyEnum...End Class`, but in VBA a class is a fat object which increases file size and requires maintenance. Someone might need ten's of enums, but ten's of classes could get a little crazy.

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Enum col: [____]: cPath: cFile: cType: End Enum 
Public Const colNames$ = "Path: cFile: cType"
```

Not directly an answer and might look pretty ugly, but I thought it might be useful to others.
In an old project I wanted to access columns with Enum (for example `row(, col.cType) = 1`).
I changed the column location, name, use, etc. pretty often, but with this lazy approach I could just rearrange the Enum and then copy paste the change in the string constant, and get the table headers:

```
Range("A1:C1").Value2 = Split(colNames, ": c")
```

Names starting with _ are [hidden](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx) by default, so `[____]` is used for padding and to avoid "`cPath = 1`"

Comment: Actually I found out - `selection.value2 = Split(colNames, ": c")` gives the first three columns the corresponding values. But the Enum and the Const should be public.

Comment: Can you elaborate more why exactly you need the [____]? I realize the dunder logic, but without it the code seems to run pretty well.

Comment: @Vityata Thanks. I wanted the names to be aligned so that I could easily notice any differences. Enums start from 0 by default, but I wanted the first item to be 1 and wanted to avoid the `cPath = 1` when changing the first item. `[____]` can be avoided by changing it to `Enum col       : cPath = 1:`

Comment: I see. My idea was that with or without the `[____]`, the `selection.value2 = Split(colNames, ": c") ` gives the same.

Comment: @Vityata ah I see, but the string constant `colNames` is not affected by the Enum. I needed it to start from 1 for the column index. For example `Cells(r, col.cPath).Value2 = strPath`

Answer (score 2):

I think that the marvel [CPearson's](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx) site has the answer with the [_First] and [_Last] trick.

I had the need of speed up a lot of DB reading just to populate combo and list boxes with values in some Office VBA application, and I just translate them to Enums.

Of course, do a `For Each` like, with the `For Next` is a must, and the `[_First]` and `[_Last]` is the way to go. The problem is that I have a lot of non-sequential Enums, each with 10 to 40 Enum items, and code for each is too tediously.

To unify all my combo and listbox feeding needs, I adapted CPearson's trick to non-sequential Enums too:

```
Sub EnumValueNamesWrapingAndUnwrapingToClipboard()
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' This creates a text string of the comma separated value names of an
        ' Enum data type. Put the cursor anywhere within an Enum definition
        ' and the code will create a comma separated string of all the
        ' enum value names. This can be used in a Select Case for validating
        ' values passed to a function. If the cursor is not within an enum
        ' definition when the code is executed, the results are unpredicable by CPearson
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim N As Long
        Dim txt As String, S As String
        Dim SL As Long, EL As Long, SC As Long, EC As Long
        Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
        Dim auxTitle As String, auxStrValue As String, strAuxCase As String
        Dim counter As Integer, EnumMin As Integer, EnumMax As Integer
        Dim auxValue As Variant
        Dim EnumIsSequential As Boolean
        
        Const STR_ENUM As String = "enum "
            If VBE.ActiveCodePane Is Nothing Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            With VBE.ActiveCodePane
                .GetSelection SL, SC, EL, EC
                With .CodeModule
                    S = .Lines(SL, 1)
                    Do Until InStr(1, S, STR_ENUM, vbTextCompare) > 0
                        N = N + 1
                        S = .Lines(SL - N, 1)
                    Loop
                    'Function title
                    auxTitle = Right$(S, Len(S) - InStr(1, S, STR_ENUM, vbTextCompare) - Len(STR_ENUM) + Len(" "))
                    N = SL - N + 1
                    S = .Lines(N, 1)
                    Do
                        S = .Lines(N, 1)
                        If InStr(1, S, "end enum", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, S, "'", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            txt = txt & " " & Trim(S) & ","
                        End If
                        N = N + 1
                    Loop Until InStr(1, S, "end enum", vbTextCompare) > 0
                    ReDim auxValue(0)
                    ReDim Preserve auxValue(0 To StringCountOccurrences(txt, "=") - 2) 'because of [_First] and [_Last]
                    For counter = 1 To UBound(auxValue)
                        auxStrValue = RetornaElementoDesignado(counter + 1, Left(txt, Len(txt) - 1))
                        If counter = 1 Then
                            EnumMin = CInt(Trim$(Right$(auxStrValue, Len(auxStrValue) - InStrRev(auxStrValue, "="))))
                            auxValue(counter) = Trim$(Left$(auxStrValue, InStr(1, auxStrValue, " = ")))
                        ElseIf counter = UBound(auxValue) Then
                            EnumMax = CInt(Trim$(Right$(auxStrValue, Len(auxStrValue) - InStrRev(auxStrValue, "="))))
                            auxValue(counter) = Trim$(Left$(auxStrValue, InStr(1, auxStrValue, " = ")))
                        Else
                            auxValue(counter) = Trim$(Left$(auxStrValue, InStr(1, auxStrValue, " = ")))
                        End If
                    Next counter
                End With
            End With
            EnumIsSequential = NumElements(auxValue) - 1 = EnumMax - EnumMin + 1
            strAuxCase = "Function ReturnNameEnum" & auxTitle & " (ByVal WhichEnum As " & auxTitle & ")As String" & vbCrLf _
                                 & "  Select Case WhichEnum" & vbCrLf
            For counter = 1 To UBound(auxValue)
                strAuxCase = strAuxCase & "     Case Is = " & auxTitle & "." & auxValue(counter) & vbCrLf _
                    & "          ReturnNameEnum" & auxTitle & " = " & ParseSpecialCharsAndDataTypeForSQL(auxValue(counter), False, True, False) & vbCrLf
            Next counter
            If EnumIsSequential Then
                strAuxCase = strAuxCase & "     Case Else" & vbCrLf _
                    & "          debug.print " & """Passed invalid """ & " & WhichEnum & " & """ WhichEnum As " & auxTitle & "! """ & vbCrLf _
                    & "    End Select" & vbCrLf _
                    & "End Function" & vbCrLf _
                    & "Function LoadEnum" & auxTitle & "InArray () As Variant" & vbCrLf _
                    & "    'If Enum is Sequential" & vbCrLf _
                    & "    Dim items() As Variant, item As Long, counter As Long" & vbCrLf _
                    & "    For item = " & auxTitle & ".[_first] To " & auxTitle & ".[_last]" & vbCrLf _
                    & "        counter = counter + 1" & vbCrLf _
                    & "    Next" & vbCrLf _
                    & "    ReDim items(counter * 2 - 1) '-1: it's 0-based..." & vbCrLf _
                    & "    For item = " & auxTitle & ".[_first] To " & auxTitle & ".[_last]" & vbCrLf _
                    & "        items(item * 2) = item" & vbCrLf _
                    & "    items(item * 2 + 1) = ReturnNameEnum" & auxTitle & "(item)" & vbCrLf _
                    & "        items(item * 2) = item" & vbCrLf _
                    & "    Next" & vbCrLf _
                    & "    LoadEnum" & auxTitle & "InArray=items()" & vbCrLf _
                    & "End Function"
            Else
                strAuxCase = strAuxCase & "     Case Else" & vbCrLf _
                  & "          debug.print " & """Passed invalid """ & " & WhichEnum & " & """ WhichEnum As " & auxTitle & "! """ & vbCrLf _
                  & "    End Select" & vbCrLf _
                  & "End Function" & vbCrLf _
                  & "Function LoadEnum" & auxTitle & "InArray () As Variant" & vbCrLf _
                  & "    'For Non-Sequential Enum" & vbCrLf _
                  & "    Dim items() As Variant, item As Long, ExistingEnum As Long" & vbCrLf _
                  & "    For item = " & auxTitle & ".[_first] To " & auxTitle & ".[_last]" & vbCrLf _
                  & "        if ReturnNameEnum" & auxTitle & "(item) <> """" then" & vbCrLf _
                  & "            ExistingEnum = ExistingEnum + 1" & vbCrLf _
                  & "            auxExistingEnum = auxExistingEnum & CStr(item) & "",""" & vbCrLf _
                  & "        end if" & vbCrLf _
                  & "    Next" & vbCrLf _
                  & "    auxExistingEnum = Left$(auxExistingEnum, Len(auxExistingEnum) - 1)" & vbCrLf _
                  & "    arrayExistingEnum = Split(auxExistingEnum, "","")" & vbCrLf _
                  & "    ReDim items(ExistingEnum * 2 - 1) '-1: it's 0-based..." & vbCrLf _
                  & "    If ReturnNameEnum" & auxTitle & "(arrayExistingEnum(item)) = """" Then GoTo continue" & vbCrLf _
                  & "        items(item * 2) = arrayExistingEnum(item)" & vbCrLf _
                  & "        items(item * 2 + 1) = ReturnNameEnum" & auxTitle & "(arrayExistingEnum(item))" & vbCrLf _
                  & "continue:" & vbCrLf _
                  & "    Next" & vbCrLf _
                  & "    LoadEnum" & auxTitle & "InArray=items()" & vbCrLf _
                  & "End Function"
            End If
            Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
            With DataObj
                .SetText strAuxCase
                .PutInClipboard
                Debug.Print strAuxCase
            End With
            Set DataObj = Nothing
        End Sub
```

I added skip comment lines - I do a lot while developing.

I did not treat Enum that is not in Ascendant order; could be done, but I'm too OCD to allow an unordered Enum ;) and ordinarily, my Enums are coming from DB with an ORDER BY on the proper value (see at end of this answer).

Of course, it depends on [_First] and [_Last] values added properly.

And, answering your question, you can do a:

```
?ReturnNameEnumWhateverNamedItIs(FruitType.Apple)
Apple
```

As a bonus, and for me the main reason to adapt the CPearson's procedure, it loads in a unidimensional array tuples of value/name of Enum; so, we can navigate all Enum values with:

```
auxArray=LoadEnumWhateverNameYouGaveItInArray()
For counter = lbound(auxArray) to ubound(auxArray) step 2
     EnumValue = auxArray(counter)
     EnumStringName = auxArray(counter+1)
Next counter
```

The procedure is generating one of two different functions `LoadEnumWhateverNameYouGaveItInArray()` versions based if Enum is sequential or not.

You can forget about the sequential; the non-sequential enum function grab both situations; I left here because I developed it first and after had to adapt it to the non-sequential case, and we never know when we'll need less code lines ;)

Notice that **although Enum is natively Long**, I used Integer in counter/EnumMin/EnumMax, just because the Enums that I need to iterate its names are less than hundred, like fruit names.

Hope it helps someone.

Edit:
To complete the explanation, this is the procedure that I use to extract Enum from tables and write them in a static module:

```
Sub CreateEnumBasedOnTableValues(ByVal EnumName As String, ByVal CnnStr As String _
   , ByVal DataS As String, ByVal strSQL As String _
   , ByVal EnumValueField As String, ByVal EnumNameField As String _
   , ByVal TreatIllegalNames As Boolean, ByVal EliminateWhiteSpaces As Boolean _
   , Optional ByVal ToEscapeWhiteSpace As String = "")
            Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
            Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
            Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
            Dim auxEnum As String, bBracket As String, eBracket As String, auxRegex As String
            Dim LastValue As Long
            
            Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
            Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
            cnn.Open CnnStr & vbCrLf & DataS
            rst.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
            If TreatIllegalNames Then bBracket = "[": eBracket = "]"
            auxEnum = "Public Enum " & EnumName & vbCrLf
            auxEnum = auxEnum & "    [_First] = "
            With rst
                .MoveFirst
                auxEnum = auxEnum & CStr(.Fields(EnumValueField)) & vbCrLf
                Do While Not .EOF
                    auxEnum = auxEnum & "    " & bBracket _
                            & IIf(EliminateWhiteSpaces, Replace(.Fields(EnumNameField), " ", ToEscapeWhiteSpace), .Fields(EnumNameField)) _
                            & eBracket & " = " & CStr(.Fields(EnumValueField)) & vbCrLf
                    LastValue = .Fields(EnumValueField)
                    .MoveNext
                Loop
                .Close
            End With
            auxEnum = auxEnum & "    [_Last] = " & CStr(LastValue) & vbCrLf
            auxEnum = auxEnum & "End Enum " & vbCrLf
            
            Set rst = Nothing
            cnn.Close
            Set cnn = Nothing
            Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
            With DataObj
                .SetText auxEnum
                .PutInClipboard
                Debug.Print auxEnum
            End With
            Set DataObj = Nothing
     End Sub
```

Just remember to pass the strSQL like that:

```
"SELECT EnumNameField, EnumValueField " & _
"FROM tblTarget WHERE EnumValueField Is NOT NULL " & _
"ORDER BY EnumValueField"
```

Usually, I use the EliminateWhiteSpaces boolean with ToEscapeWhiteSpace = "_", but is a personal preference.

Comment: Interesting! But requires trusted access to VBA object model.

Comment: @johnywhy: it is true; only trusted access to VBA obj model: it is not possible in Outlook, for example.

Comment: Where/what's the code of the function ReturnNameEnumWhateverNamedItIs()?

Comment: @6diegodiego9: the code is autogenerated to the Clipboard by the `Sub EnumValueNamesWrapingAndUnwrapingToClipboard()` has a line, after the 2nd `End With` that: `strAuxCase = "Function ReturnNameEnum" & auxTitle & " (ByVal WhichEnum As " & auxTitle & ")As String" & vbCrLf  & "  Select Case WhichEnum" & vbCrLf` and this will prefix your choosed EnumName `auxTitle ` with `Function ReturnNameEnum`...

Comment: Am I reading correctly that the non-sequential version is designed for powers of 2?

Comment: @MarkE. both versions deals with what I explained in the paragraph " _it loads in a unidimensional array tuples of value/name of Enum_ "

Comment: Thanks, I'm just having a hard time understanding how it works.  I get the idea of looping from the start number to the end number and checking for each, as Skip does.  I also get that this is inefficient if they aren't sequential.  I'm trying to figure out what algorithm might avoid skipping through each number, though.  If you knew they were all powers of 2 it would make sense, but I can't quite tell.

Answer (score 1):

For above "John Coleman"'s example I suggest to use next functions:

```
Function FruitType2Int(Fruit As FruitType)
    FruitType2Int = Format("0", Fruit)
    Debug.Print FruitType2Int
End Function

Function int2FruitString(i As Integer) As String
    If i = FruitType2Int(Orange) Then
        int2FruitString = "Orange"
    ElseIf i = FruitType2Int(Plum) Then
        int2FruitString = "Plum"
    ElseIf i = FruitType2Int(Apple) Then
        int2FruitString = "Apple"
    Else
        int2FruitString = "?"
    End If
    Debug.Print int2FruitString
End Function
```

Direct use of an `Array` indexes (without *LBound()* and etc.) may cause different resuts, depends on value in `Option Base 1`

Comment: Even though few VBA programmers use `Option Base 1`, this answer is helpful for those who do, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I wrote to get the enumeration member name from the value supplied. Additionally, it will list the enum names in a module, or list constant names in a module.

```
Public Enum CodeInfoEnum
    ciEnums
    ciConstants
End Enum


'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure     : CodeInfo
'
' Author        : RMittelman@gmail.com
'
' Purpose       : Searches a module for enumerations & constants
'
' History       :   11/13/2022  Original version
'                   11/14/2022  Added feature to list enums in the module
'                   11/14/2022  Added feature to list constants inn the module
'
' Parameters    :
'
'   CodeType    : A CodeInfoEnum member indicating Enums or Constants
'
'   ModuleName  : Optional. Name of module containing ItemName
'                   If missing, defaults to the module this function is called from
'
'   ItemName    : Optional. Name of the enumeration to examine
'                   If "?" or missing, returns a list of enumerations in the module
'
'   EnumValue   : optional. Value of the enumeration member wanted
'                   If missing, defaults to 0
'                   Ignored if CodType is not ciEnums
'                   Ignored if ItemName is missing or "?"
'
' Returns       : - The text value of the enumeration value supplied; or
'                 - A list of enumeration names in the module; or
'                 - A list of constant names in the module
'
' Notes         : Only searches in the module's Declarations section
'
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Public Function CodeInfo(CodeType As CodeInfoEnum, Optional ModuleName As Variant, Optional ItemName As String = "?", Optional EnumValueWanted As Variant) As String

    Dim myApp       As Access.Application
    Dim compMod     As Object
    
    Dim modLines    As Long
    Dim procStart   As Long
    Dim procLines   As Long
    Dim idx         As Long
    Dim codeText    As String
    Dim foundItem   As Boolean
    Dim foundMember As Boolean
    Dim tempVal     As Variant
    Dim enumVal     As Long
    
    CodeInfo = ""
    Set myApp = CurrentProject.Application
    
    If IsMissing(ModuleName) Then ModuleName = Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule
    If ModuleName <> "" Then
    
        Set compMod = myApp.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName).CodeModule
        With compMod
        
            ' get declaration code
            modLines = .CountOfLines
            procStart = 1
            procLines = .CountOfDeclarationLines
        
            ' search code text for enumeration(s)
            idx = 0
            foundItem = False
            Do While (Not foundItem) And (idx <= procLines)
            
                idx = idx + 1
                codeText = .Lines(idx, 1)
            
                ' if ItemName is "?", build list of all desired items
                If ItemName = "?" Then
                    Select Case CodeType
                        Case CodeInfoEnum.ciEnums
                            If codeText Like "*Enum *" Then
                                tempVal = Trim$(Mid$(codeText, InStr(1, codeText, "Enum", vbTextCompare) + 4))
                                CodeInfo = CodeInfo & "," & tempVal
                            End If
                        Case CodeInfoEnum.ciConstants
                            If codeText Like "*Const *" Then
                                tempVal = Mid$(codeText, InStr(1, codeText, "Const", vbTextCompare) + 6)
                                tempVal = Trim$(Left$(tempVal, InStr(1, tempVal, " ")))
                                CodeInfo = CodeInfo & "," & tempVal
                            End If
                    End Select
            
                ' otherwise, just see if we can find ItemName wanted
                Else
                    foundItem = codeText Like "*Enum " & ItemName
                End If
            
            Loop
        
            ' if a specific Enum is found, look for the value wanted
            If foundItem Then
                enumVal = 0
                foundMember = False
                codeText = ""
                Do While (Not foundMember) And (idx <= procLines) And (Not codeText Like "*End Enum")
                    idx = idx + 1
                    codeText = .Lines(idx, 1)
                    If codeText Like "*=*" Then
                        tempVal = Trim$(Split(codeText, "=")(1))
                        If IsNumeric(tempVal) Then enumVal = CLng(tempVal)
                    End If
                    If enumVal = EnumValueWanted Then
                        CodeInfo = Trim$(Split(codeText, "=")(0))
                        foundMember = True
                    End If
                    enumVal = enumVal + 1
                Loop
            End If
        
        End With
        If CodeInfo Like ",*" Then CodeInfo = Mid$(CodeInfo, 2)
    
    End If

    Set compMod = Nothing
    Set myApp = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. Seems interesting, but I am not sure it works the way you think it works. You might consider taking a look at this: `?CodeInfo(ciEnums,itemname:="CodeInfoEnum",enumvaluewanted:=2)`. Furthermore, cosider rewriting it, so it could be worked in both Excel and Access, this is how the Excel version looks like - https://gist.github.com/Vitosh/479a8a447fec6a28a4afbc8aa9ce6ecc

Comment: Thanks for the comment Vityata.  After checking out your code on github, it looks like the only difference is in how you declare and instantiate the myApp object unless I missed something else.  I'm not sure what you mean by "not sure it works like you think it works".  I will try to do this in Excel to see how to rework the declaration.  But please clarify why you think it may not work other than the myApp object.

Comment: Just realized that both Access & Excel (and probably Word also) have the Application object.  So I removed the declaration, instantiation and destroyer of myApp, and changed all references of myApp to Application.  Now it works in both Access & Excel.

Comment: If you run this in the immediate window, then you will see some strange result: `?CodeInfo(ciEnums,itemname:="CodeInfoEnum",enumvaluewanted:=2)` The question mark in front is important.

Comment: @Vityata, I still don't understand the strange result you are seeing.  When I execute the above in the immediate window, I get a blank line as a result, since there is no value # 2. If I use 0 or 1 instead, I get the enum member name.  What are you seeing that is different? Please supply any error message you get. Thanks...

Comment: Not an error, but `End Enum` and I am not 100% sure this is what was expected. :)

Answer (score 0):

Any method which does not return a keyed collection or (preferably a scripting dictionary) will be prone to errors if the enumeration range is not a contiguous range, such as the case where you are using the enumeration to map to bits.  My solution to this has been to develop a class of 'EnumerationDictionary' which allows arrays of the enumeration or the enumeration names to be returned, and name to be looked up given an enumeration and a string to be used to retrieve an enumeration.  The example below is for colours in a word document and shows how to combine an internal enumeration with additional user defined values.  Its a bit clunky but works very well.

```
Option Explicit

' A new enumeration for colour has been created to allow
' the inclusion of custom colours
' The wdColor enumeration values are the RGB vlaue as a decimal signed long
' For the hexadecimal representation the colours are BGR not RGB
' e.g. 0xXXBBGGRR not Ox00RRGGBB

Public Enum UserColour
    Aqua = wdColorAqua                                                     '13421619    0x00CCCC33
    Automatic = wdColorAutomatic                                           '-16777216   0xFF000000
    Black = wdColorBlack                                                   '0           0x00000000
    Blue = wdColorBlue                                                     '16711680    0x00FF0000
    BlueGray = wdColorBlueGray                                             '10053222
    BrightGreen = wdColorBrightGreen                                       '65280       0x0000FF00
    Brown = wdColorBrown                                                   '13209
    DarkBlue = wdColorDarkBlue                                             '8388608
    DarkGreen = wdColorDarkGreen                                           '13056
    DarkRed = wdColorDarkRed                                               '128         0x00000080
    DarkTeal = wdColorDarkTeal                                             '6697728
    DarkYellow = wdColorDarkYellow                                         '32896
    Gold = wdColorGold                                                     '52479
    Gray05 = wdColorGray05                                                 '15987699
    Gray10 = wdColorGray10                                                 '15132390
    Gray125 = wdColorGray125                                               '14737632
    Gray15 = wdColorGray15                                                 '14277081
    Gray20 = wdColorGray20                                                 '13421772
    Gray25 = wdColorGray25                                                 '12632256
    Gray30 = wdColorGray30                                                 '11776947
    Gray35 = wdColorGray35                                                 '10921638
    Gray375 = wdColorGray375                                               '10526880
    Gray40 = wdColorGray40                                                 '10066329
    Gray45 = wdColorGray45                                                 '9211020
    Gray50 = wdColorGray50                                                 '8421504
    Gray55 = wdColorGray55                                                 '7566195
    Gray60 = wdColorGray60                                                 '6710886
    Gray625 = wdColorGray625                                               '6316128
    Gray65 = wdColorGray65                                                 '5855577
    Gray70 = wdColorGray70                                                 '5000268
    Gray75 = wdColorGray75                                                 '4210752
    Gray80 = wdColorGray80                                                 '3355443
    Gray85 = wdColorGray85                                                 '2500134
    Gray875 = wdColorGray875                                               '2105376
    Gray90 = wdColorGray90                                                 '1644825
    Gray95 = wdColorGray95                                                 '789516
    Green = wdColorGreen                                                   '32768
    Indigo = wdColorIndigo                                                 '10040115
    Lavender = wdColorLavender                                             '16751052
    LightBlue = wdColorLightBlue                                           '16737843
    LightGreen = wdColorLightGreen                                         '13434828
    LightOrange = wdColorLightOrange                                       '39423
    LightTurquoise = wdColorLightTurquoise                                 '16777164
    LightYellow = wdColorLightYellow                                       '10092543
    Lime = wdColorLime                                                     '52377
    OliveGreen = wdColorOliveGreen                                         '13107
    Orange = wdColorOrange                                                 '26367
    PaleBlue = wdColorPaleBlue                                             '16764057
    Pink = wdColorPink                                                     '16711935
    Plum = wdColorPlum                                                     '6697881
    Red = wdColorRed                                                       '255         0x000000FF
    Rose = wdColorRose                                                     '13408767
    SeaGree = wdColorSeaGreen                                              '6723891
    SkyBlue = wdColorSkyBlue                                               '16763904
    Tan = wdColorTan                                                       '10079487
    Teal = wdColorTeal                                                     '8421376
    Turquoise = wdColorTurquoise                                           '16776960
    Violet = wdColorViolet                                                 '8388736
    White = wdColorWhite                                                   '16777215    0x00FFFFFF
    Yellow = wdColorYellow                                                 '65535
    ' Add custom s from this point onwards
    HeadingBlue = &H993300                                                 'RGB(0,51,153)   0x00993300
    HeadingGreen = &H92D050                                                'RGB(146,208,80) 0x0050D092

End Enum


Private Type Properties

    enum_gets_string                           As Scripting.Dictionary
    string_gets_enum                           As Scripting.Dictionary

End Type

Private p                                       As Properties

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set p.enum_gets_string = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set p.string_gets_enum = New Scripting.Dictionary

    With p.enum_gets_string

        .Add Key:=Aqua, Item:="Aqua"
        .Add Key:=Automatic, Item:="Automatic"
        .Add Key:=Black, Item:="Black"
        .Add Key:=Blue, Item:="Blue"
        .Add Key:=BlueGray, Item:="BlueGray"
        .Add Key:=BrightGreen, Item:="BrightGreen"
        .Add Key:=Brown, Item:="Brown"
        .Add Key:=DarkBlue, Item:="DarkBlue"
        .Add Key:=DarkGreen, Item:="DarkGreen"
        .Add Key:=DarkRed, Item:="DarkRed"
        .Add Key:=DarkTeal, Item:="DarkTeal"
        .Add Key:=DarkYellow, Item:="DarkYellow"
        .Add Key:=Gold, Item:="Gold"
        .Add Key:=Gray05, Item:="Gray05"
        .Add Key:=Gray10, Item:="Gray10"
        .Add Key:=Gray125, Item:="Gray125"
        .Add Key:=Gray15, Item:="Gray15"
        .Add Key:=Gray20, Item:="Gray20"
        .Add Key:=Gray25, Item:="Gray25"
        .Add Key:=Gray30, Item:="Gray30"
        .Add Key:=Gray35, Item:="Gray35"
        .Add Key:=Gray375, Item:="Gray375"
        .Add Key:=Gray40, Item:="Gray40"
        .Add Key:=Gray45, Item:="Gray45"
        .Add Key:=Gray50, Item:="Gray50"
        .Add Key:=Gray55, Item:="Gray55"
        .Add Key:=Gray60, Item:="Gray60"
        .Add Key:=Gray625, Item:="Gray625"
        .Add Key:=Gray65, Item:="Gray65"
        .Add Key:=Gray70, Item:="Gray70"
        .Add Key:=Gray75, Item:="Gray75"
        .Add Key:=Gray80, Item:="Gray80"
        .Add Key:=Gray85, Item:="Gray85"
        .Add Key:=Gray875, Item:="Gray875"
        .Add Key:=Gray90, Item:="Gray90"
        .Add Key:=Gray95, Item:="Gray95"
        .Add Key:=Green, Item:="Green"
        .Add Key:=Indigo, Item:="Indigo"
        .Add Key:=Lavender, Item:="Lavender"
        .Add Key:=LightBlue, Item:="LightBlue"
        .Add Key:=LightGreen, Item:="LightGreen"
        .Add Key:=LightOrange, Item:="LightOrange"
        .Add Key:=LightTurquoise, Item:="LightTurquoise"
        .Add Key:=LightYellow, Item:="LightYellow"
        .Add Key:=Lime, Item:="Lime"
        .Add Key:=OliveGreen, Item:="OliveGreen"
        .Add Key:=Orange, Item:="Orange"
        .Add Key:=PaleBlue, Item:="PaleBlue"
        .Add Key:=Pink, Item:="Pink"
        .Add Key:=Plum, Item:="Plum"
        .Add Key:=Red, Item:="Red"
        .Add Key:=Rose, Item:="Rose"
        .Add Key:=SeaGree, Item:="SeaGreen"
        .Add Key:=SkyBlue, Item:="SkyBlue"
        .Add Key:=Tan, Item:="Tan"
        .Add Key:=Teal, Item:="Teal"
        .Add Key:=Turquoise, Item:="Turquoise"
        .Add Key:=Violet, Item:="Violet"
        .Add Key:=White, Item:="White"
        .Add Key:=Yellow, Item:="Yellow"
        .Add Key:=HeadingBlue, Item:="HeadingBlue"
        .Add Key:=HeadingGreen, Item:="HeadingGreen"

    End With

    ' Now compile the reverse lookup
    Set p.string_gets_enum = ReverseDictionary(p.enum_gets_string, "Reversing userCOLOUR.enum_gets_string")

End Sub

Public Property Get Items() As Variant
    proj.Log.Trace s.locale, "{0}.Items", TypeName(Me)

    Set Items = p.enum_gets_string.Items

End Property


Public Property Get Enums() As Variant
' Returns an array of Enums")

    Set Enums = p.enum_gets_string.Keys

End Property


Public Property Get Item(ByVal this_enum As UserColour) As String
' Returns the Item for a given Enum")

    Item = p.enum_gets_string.Item(this_enum)

End Property


' VBA will not allow a property/function Item of 'Enum' so we use
' ü (alt+0252) to sidestep the keyword clash for this property Item
Public Property Get Enüm(ByVal this_item As String) As UserColour

    Enüm = p.string_gets_enum.Item(this_item)

End Property


Public Function HoldsEnum(ByVal this_enum As UserColour) As Boolean

    HoldsEnum = p.enum_gets_string.Exists(this_enum)

End Function


Public Function LacksEnum(ByVal this_enum As UserColour) As Boolean

    LacksEnum = Not Me.HoldsEnum(this_enum)

End Function


Public Function HoldsItem(ByVal this_item As String) As Boolean

    HoldsItem = p.string_gets_enum.Exists(this_item)

End Function


Public Function LacksItem(ByVal this_item As String) As Boolean

    LacksItem = Not Me.HoldsItem(this_item)

End Function


Public Function Count() As Long

    Count = p.enum_gets_string.Count

End Function
```

Plus the following utility to reverse dictionaries.

```
Public Function ReverseDictionary(ByRef this_dict As Scripting.Dictionary) As Scripting.Dictionary
' Swaps keys for items in scripting.dictionaries.
' Keys and items must be unique which is usually the case for an enumeration

    Dim my_key                                  As Variant
    Dim my_keys                                 As Variant
    Dim my_reversed_map                         As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim my_message                              As String

    On Error GoTo key_is_not_unique
    Set my_reversed_map = New Scripting.Dictionary
    my_keys = this_dict.Keys

    For Each my_key In my_keys

        my_reversed_map.Add Key:=this_dict.Item(my_key), Item:=my_key

    Next

    Set ReverseDictionary = my_reversed_map
    Exit Function

key_is_not_unique:

    On Error GoTo 0

    MsgBox _
        Title:="Reverse Dictionary Error", _
        Prompt:="The key and item are not unique Key:=" & my_key & " Item:= " & this_dict.Item(my_key), _
        Buttons:=vbOKOnly

    Set ReverseDictionary = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: But do these enums give you intellisense?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to some other answers here. In this example, "ExecutionMode" is the name of the enum.

```
Public Const ExecutionModes As String = "Development, Testing, Production"
Enum ExecutionMode
          Development
          Testing
          Production
End Enum


Function EnumToString(lEnum As Long, sList As String) As String
' return list-item by enum
          Dim aList
          aList = Split(sList, ",")
          aList = Application.Trim(aList)

          EnumToString = aList(lEnum + 1)
End Function


Function StringToEnum(sItem As String, sList As String) As Long
' return listposition of string
' this only works for ordered, sequential enums
          Dim vArray
          vArray = Split(sList, ",")
          vArray = Application.Trim(vArray)

          Dim lPos As Long
          lPos = Application.Match(sItem, vArray, 0) - 1

          StringToEnum = lPos
End Function


Function ExecMode(sMode as String) As ExecutionMode
' return active mode of book, as enum
' Development, Testing, or Production
          ExecMode = StringToEnum(sMode, ExecutionModes)
End Function

Function ExecModeStr(eMode as ExecutionMode)As String
' return mode as string
          ExecModeStr = EnumToString(eMode, ExecutionModes)
End Function
```

Drawback: This only works for ordered, sequential enums, i.e., 0, 1,2,3,4, etc. If your enum values are anything else (e.g., 2, 4, 6 or &H80000000, &H80000002) then this solution will fail.

I'm sure it could be made to work with arbitrary numbers, but the trick is to minimize redundant typing *and* keep IntelliSense. I think some of the other answers here suffer from one or more of these problems:

- Requires sequential items starting from 0 or 1,
- or, Requires typing names or values or both twice,
- or, Doesn't provide IntelliSense.
- or, Requires Trusted Access to VBA

This solution already requires typing the labels twice. If a solution to arbitrary values requires typing the values twice then I don't consider very usable.

Creating your own enum structure seems promising. But the question is:
**Which VBA data-structure will give you IntelliSense for items?**

Type, Enum, Class, Module... aren't data-structures. Array, Collection, and Dictionary don't give IntelliSense for items. If we can find a data-structure will give you IntelliSense for items, then we have a viable solution to this question. I've read XML might help here.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to look this up is by utilizing the Object Browser built into the VBA editor.  If the enum is user-defined, you will need to execute the code in the VBA editor window that contains the enum to load it into memory, then you should be able to view it in the Object Browser by going to View -> Object Browser or by pressing F2.  Once opened, you can view all of the enums and their constant values.

[image: TestEnum]

[image: View_ObjectBrowser]

[image: TestEnumInObjectBrowser]

If the enum is built-in (*not* user-defined), you will need to look up the name of the enum in the Object Browser in order to obtain its values.  Generally, these are prefixed with either Mso (Microsoft Office), Xl (only for Excel), or Vb (Visual Basic).  For instance:

Mso:

[image: MsoAlertButtonOKCancel]

Xl:

[image: XlYesNoGuess]

Vb:

[image: VbMsgBoxResult]

Comment: The question was about programmatic access to the enum names, not simply viewing them in the tooling.

Comment: Vityata expressed in one of his comments that he is asking out of curiosity, so he may not be worried about whether it is programmatic and may have asked the question in the way he did because he hadn't considered there may have been more practical ways. Many of the other examples are extremely verbose compared to the C# version and some of the answers aren't technically answering his question, anyway, but instead are just printing hard-coded strings, but he's not complaining about the answers.  He's just curious, so I think he's open-minded about the answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy if you use the [Enum Builder in Code VBA](https://www.codevba.com/help/enum_builder.htm) (image below):

1. Give enum name and values,
2. Check Enum_ToString which adds code returning the enum value name string for a given enum value,
3. Check Declare Enum with First and Last to have these attributes added to the enum ... and press OK which inserts the code.

Now in the Immediate Window insert the single line block of code

```
For i = Fruit.[_First] To Fruit.[_Last]: ?Fruit_ToString(cint(i)): Next
```

When [Enter] returns the required list.

[image: Enum Builder with function Enum_ToString and adding attributes _First and _Last checked]

Answer (score 0):

I realized that in some cases the code was returning the "End Enum" statement if I supplied a value 1 higher than the last enumeration member, so I fixed the code for that.  Here is the latest code, including making it work with Access or Excel:

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure     : CodeInfo
'
' Author        : RMittelman@gmail.com
'
' Purpose       : Searches a module for enumerations & constants
'
' History       :   11/13/2022  Original version
'                   11/14/2022  Added feature to list enums in the module
'                   11/14/2022  Added feature to list constants inn the module
'                   11/15/2022  Fixed error returning "End Enum" statement
'
' Parameters    :
'
'   CodeType    : A CodeInfoEnum member indicating Enums or Constants
'
'   ModuleName  : Optional. Name of module containing ItemName
'                   If missing, defaults to the module this function is called from
'
'   ItemName    : Optional. Name of the enumeration to examine
'                   If "?" or missing, returns a list of enumerations in the module
'
'   EnumValue   : optional. Value of the enumeration member wanted
'                   If missing, defaults to 0
'                   Ignored if CodType is not ciEnums
'                   Ignored if ItemName is missing or "?"
'
' Returns       : - The text value of the enumeration value supplied; or
'                 - A list of enumeration names in the module; or
'                 - A list of constant names in the module
'
' Notes         : Only searches in the module's Declarations section
'
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Public Function CodeInfo(CodeType As CodeInfoEnum, Optional ModuleName As Variant, Optional ItemName As String = "?", Optional EnumValueWanted As Variant) As String

    Dim compMod     As Object
    
    Dim modLines    As Long
    Dim procStart   As Long
    Dim procLines   As Long
    Dim idx         As Long
    Dim codeText    As String
    Dim foundItem   As Boolean
    Dim foundMember As Boolean
    Dim tempVal     As Variant
    Dim enumVal     As Long
    
    CodeInfo = ""
    
    If IsMissing(ModuleName) Then ModuleName = Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule
    If ModuleName <> "" Then
        
        Set compMod = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName).CodeModule
        With compMod
            
            ' get declaration code
            modLines = .CountOfLines
            procStart = 1
            procLines = .CountOfDeclarationLines
            
            ' search code text for enumeration(s)
            idx = 0
            foundItem = False
            Do While (Not foundItem) And (idx <= procLines)
                
                idx = idx + 1
                codeText = .Lines(idx, 1)
                
                ' if ItemName is "?", build list of all desired items
                If ItemName = "?" Then
                    Select Case CodeType
                        Case CodeInfoEnum.ciEnums
                            If codeText Like "*Enum *" Then
                                tempVal = Trim$(Mid$(codeText, InStr(1, codeText, "Enum", vbTextCompare) + 4))
                                CodeInfo = CodeInfo & "," & tempVal
                            End If
                        Case CodeInfoEnum.ciConstants
                            If codeText Like "*Const *" Then
                                tempVal = Mid$(codeText, InStr(1, codeText, "Const", vbTextCompare) + 6)
                                tempVal = Trim$(Left$(tempVal, InStr(1, tempVal, " ")))
                                CodeInfo = CodeInfo & "," & tempVal
                            End If
                    End Select
                
                ' otherwise, just see if we can find ItemName wanted
                Else
                    foundItem = codeText Like "*Enum " & ItemName
                End If
                
            Loop
            
            ' if a specific Enum is found, look for the value wanted
            If foundItem Then
                
                enumVal = 0
                foundMember = False
                codeText = ""
                
                Do While (Not foundMember) And (idx <= procLines) And (Not codeText Like "*End Enum")
                    
                    idx = idx + 1
                    codeText = .Lines(idx, 1)
                    
                    ' don't process the "End Enum" statement
                    If Not codeText Like "*End Enum" Then
                        
                        ' reset the next enum value if the member has a specific value
                        If codeText Like "*=*" Then
                            tempVal = Trim$(Split(codeText, "=")(1))
                            If IsNumeric(tempVal) Then enumVal = CLng(tempVal)
                        End If
                        
                        If enumVal = EnumValueWanted Then
                            CodeInfo = Trim$(Split(codeText, "=")(0))
                            foundMember = True
                        End If
                        
                    End If
                    enumVal = enumVal + 1
                    
                Loop
            End If
            
        End With
        If CodeInfo Like ",*" Then CodeInfo = Mid$(CodeInfo, 2)
        
    End If
    
    Set compMod = Nothing

End Function
```