# How to declare type that isn't variable

Tags: excel, vba, list, types, enums

How to declare type whose declared children I can call by name?

Some thing like this:

delphi:

```
TSuit = (Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs, Spades)
```

I want to declare list of items, they don't need to contain value, which I can call while writing code to make code more readable and easier to modify.

I tried this but I can't figure out how to do it:

declaration:

```
Public Enum EType
    square = 0
    triangle = 1
    circle = 2
End Enum

Public Sub LOK(line As Byte, SlType As EType)
    MsgBox ("test")
End Sub
```

calling:

```
LOK(1, square)
```

Is this even possible in VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`circle` seems to be a reserved key word and cannot be used. If you change it to something else like `eCircle` everthing works as intended.

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum EType
    eSquare = 0
    eTriangle = 1
    eCircle = 2
End Enum

Public Sub LOK(line As Byte, SlType As EType)
    MsgBox "test: " & SlType
End Sub

Sub test()
    LOK 1, eSquare
    LOK 1, eTriangle
    LOK 1, eCircle
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Sorry Vityata he was faster :)
Why does it work without brackets? it was defined with ()...

Comment: Thank you for fast explanation :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `Call` keyword. `Call LOK(1, eCircle)` is equivalent to `LOK 1, eCircle`.

Answer (score 2):

Run `TestMe` and the Messagebox should appear:

```
Public Enum EType
    square = 1
    triangle = 2
    kolelo = 3
End Enum

Public Sub LOK(line As Byte, SlType As EType)
    MsgBox ("test")
End Sub

Sub TestMe()
    LOK 1, square
End Sub
```

However, if you are trying to actually get the word behind the enumeration, e.g. print "square" or "triangle" or "kolelo" (circle is a reserved word), then there is no easy direct way to do it.

For the workaround, take a look at the solutions here - [Is there a way to get the enums in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578348/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-enums-in-vba)